# Using awk, how do I match pattern and variants?

Tags: regex, unix, awk

I've been struggling with this for a while in regex testers but what came up as a correct regex pattern actually failed. I've got a large file, tab delimited, with numerous types of data. I want to print a specific column, with the characters XYZ, and it's subsequent values.

In the specific column I'm interested in I have values like:

```
XYZ

ABCDE

XYZ/WORDS

XYZ/ABCDE

ABFE

XYZ
```

regex tester that was successful was something like:

```
XYZ(.....)*
```

It obviously fails when implemented as:

```
awk '{if ($1=="XYZ(......)*") print$0}'
```

What regex character do I use to denote that I want everything after the backslash(/), including the original pattern (XYZ)?

Specifically, I want to be able to capture all instances of XYZ, and print the other columns that go along with them (hence the print$0). Specifically, capture these values:

```
XYZ 

XYZ/WORDS

XYZ/ABCDE
```

Thank you

Comment: why don't you match on the last line of input (`XYZ`)? does your input file actually have blank lines (as shown) and if so how do you determine which blank lines to keep vs discard (eg, keep the blank line before, or after, a line that starts with `XYZ`)? if your input file does not contain blank lines then please update the question to remove said blank lines (from both input and output)

Answer (score 0):

Setup: (assuming actual data file does not include blank lines)

```
$ cat x
XYZ 1 2 3 4
ABCDE 1 2 3 4
XYZ/WORDS 1 2 3 4
XYZ/ABCDE 1 2 3 4
ABFE 1 2 3 4
XYZ 1 2 3 4
```

If you merely want to print all rows where the first field starts with `XYZ`:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^XYZ/' x
XYZ 1 2 3 4
XYZ/WORDS 1 2 3 4
XYZ/ABCDE 1 2 3 4
XYZ 1 2 3 4
```

If this doesn't provide the expected results then please update the question with more details (to include a more representative set of input data and the expected output).

Comment: note that if the input is tab-delimited as per the question, `-F '\t'` or equivalent should be used to correctly handle empty fields and fields containing non-tab whitespace

Comment: @markp-fuso Your comment and code did produce the expected results, very helpful. Thank you! To your comment about white spaces, the input file was tab delimitted and does not include blank spaces. However, it does not seem to effect the output in this case.

Comment: @SamGROW `awk` default field separator (`-F` aka `FS`) is white space (space(s) or tab(s)) so, correct, won't make a difference in this case; where an issue could be found is if the 1st field has all white space in which case my `$1` reference would actually match the first field with non-white space characters; your sample data doesn't seem to indicate white space in the 1st field, and your `awk` code doesn't make use of the `-F` flag ... so I opted for brevity in this case; you could certainly add `-F'\t'` (or `BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}`) and should still get the same results

Comment: @SamGROW looking at  your question history you may want to review [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and consider reviewing some of the past answers you've received; regards